Second Highest Salary not working with `IFNULL( )`
Write a solution to find the second highest salary from the Employee table. If there is no second highest salary, return null.
This is my code:
    select ifnull(x.salary,NULL) as SecondHighestSalary
    from(
        select *, 
           dense_rank() over( order by salary) as rnk
           from Employee
    ) x
    where x.rnk =2

It is passing all test case but not able to pass only 1 test case.
Employee:



id
salary




1
100



Output:



SecondHighestSalary



Expected output:



SecondHighestSalary




null



Still don't know why IFNULL is not working.
Can someone please tell me why 1 test case is failing?

What's the expected result if two employees have the same highest salary?

I reckon you should be handling this in your presentation layer.  If you get back an empty result set, you would know that there is only one employee available, and you can report the second highest as NULL based on that.

How are you blindly adding x.rnk =2. If your employee table have two or more highest salary paid person (same highest salary), then that was create issue. So, change the logic.

You can use a good, old subquery with MAX rather than a window function. This will return NULL if no second highest salary exists:
SELECT 
  MAX(salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
WHERE 
  salary < (SELECT MAX(salary)
             FROM Employee);

See this sample fiddle

awesome ... @JonasMetzler

try:
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT salary 
        FROM Employee 
        ORDER BY salary DESC 
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
    ) AS SecondHighestSalary;


@DigantDixit How are you blindly adding x.rnk =2? 
If Employee table have two or more highest salary paid persons (same highest salary), then that was create issue.
So, need to change the logic. First, find rank depends on DISTINCT salary data and then continue your logic.
I have update query according to your current logic:
select ifnull(x.salary,NULL) as SecondHighestSalary
    from(
        select distinct salary, 
           dense_rank() over( order by salary desc ) as rnk
           from Employee
    ) x
    where x.rnk =2

Sample query: db<>fiddle

What do you mean? Here we have 2 max persons, the result of OP's query is correctly the second highest value: https://dbfiddle.uk/11RHmQBw

Yes, @JonasMetzler this answer and your posted answer is correct. In my post I ask that to the person who posted this ...

I used OP's query in the fiddle in my comment, not yours. As you see, the result of their query is correct for this case. So what issue do you talk about?

Yes, that not an issue. I added an alternative solution according to user logic in the question . . .
